# Error en consulta en codeiniter 4

Tags: sql, codeigniter-4

Estoy realizando esta consulta en codeigniter4 y me encuentro estancado

```
public function consultasHoy(){

        $data = $this->consultas->select('pacientes.*,consultas_hc.*')
            ->from('consultas_hc')
            ->join('pacientes','consultas_hc.identificacion = pacientes.identificacion')
            ->where(date_format('consultas_rc.reConsulta','%Y-%m-%d'),date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
            ->orderBy('consultas_hc.reConsulta', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

y me devuelve este error.

```
date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola la respuesta para el error fue la siguiente

```
public function consultasHoy(){

        helper('date');
        $hoy=(new \DateTime("now"))->format("Y-m-d");

        $builder = $this->consultas->select('*');
        $builder->join('pacientes', 'pacientes.identificacion=consultas_hc.identificacion');
        $builder->where("DATE(reConsulta)", $hoy);
        $query   = $builder->get();


        return json_encode($query->getResult());
    }
```

Comment: Sin eso me estuvo devolviendo error en la consulta, busque un poco y encontré eso como solución.